# How to preload text than load images?

Tags: javascript, html, load

I've made a site and I want text and forms load firstly, than images

Comment: @ali if you would like to load text first don't write the src value to your images, add it on dom ready with javascript.

Comment: is there any "javascript.preload" or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read again about browser load order here:

http://ejohn.org/blog/browser-page-load-performance/

to make sure the image load after document content, you can use some javascript library for image lazy load:

e.g: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Yes, but what about form-s.....

is there any "javascript.preload" or something like that

Comment: when use image lazy load, html (include forms), javascript, css will load completely before image. you can use Google Chrome Audits Tool to optimize your website loading progress :D